# Finding MongoDB documents with duplicate `_id`

Tags: mongodb

I am running in to a duplicate `_id` issue while trying to restore the DB dump.

```
Failed: bulk write error: [{[{can't have multiple _id fields in one document}]},
```

And want to find out which document it is so I can remove it.
I have tried `aggregate` with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$_id", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }
]);
```

The `_id` is of the form

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55ad085569702d6a820007b3" }
```

But the aggregate is not giving any result and I am not sure if the statement has an error.

Is it not possible to aggregate on the `_id` itself?
Thank you.

Comment: A mongo collection will not have a duplicate "_id". When you are trying to restore the duplicate key error is because your mongodump contains the documents that have the same "_id" that are in the mongo db collection

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is the issue. How could the dump have duplicate `_id` documents, but not the collection itself?

Comment: your bulk write error indicates your dump document contains multiple _id, you'd need to investigate your dump to check if it contains a document that has multiple _id fields.

Comment: Mongo itself won't allow you to insert documents like these
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19361

Comment: Thank you @AnuragWagh. Yes it looks like a document has two `_id` fields with one being `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "can't have multiple _id fields in one document" is not indicating a duplicate key error where multiple documents have the same value for _id.

It is indicating that a single document has more than one field named _id.

You might try using the `bsondump` utility to extract the bson files from the dump directory to examine the documents directly.